# Font size too big in ie9

Tags: layout, internet-explorer-9, font-face, font-size

I am having quite a problem here. Some computers with ie9 are displaying my fonts too big and breaking my layout. I have changed the entire webpage to em's in a desperate attempt to fix this problem but the problem is still there. The information I have comes from the clients client. so I have no way of looking at their computer but I have a screen shot.
[image: font size breaks layout in website]

The actual website is http://earlbutler.com

all I know about the computer its breaking on is. browser:IE9 OS:Win7 Laptop

Thanks so much in advance, I know you guys are rockstars!

****Edit****
Its been 5 days without an answer. What else do you guys need from me. Let me know. I just cannot figure this one out.

Comment: I tried it with IE9 on my Win7 box and could not reproduce the error, all of the scaling and fonts looks good to me. Is it possible they have something funky setup in the users browser?

Comment: Its Possible, But I researched it, and I couldn't find anywhere that you can increase font size in ie9. All you can do is zoom. It is also possible that they have some sort of user stylesheet, but that seems unlikely.

Comment: I lied, I just found the text size button. But that is still a null point as my layout is in em's

Answer (score 0):

This problem occurs when your base font size is specified in ems or as a percentage, and the user changes the default text size in their browser (instead of using page zoom).

You want to **set your body font size to 16px** (or whatever your desired base size is.) This effectively disables text zoom, which I'm perfectly ok with. Page zoom is still an option for users, and is usually a better one - especially for responsive builds.

In IE 9, here's where that setting is located if you'd like to test this behavior:

[image: Text size location in ie9]

To get the command bar with that page dropdown to show up in the first place, right click above the address bar and click "Command Bar". Took me forever to find it.